# После выбора файла в input он перенаправляет на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, css, html5, веб-программирование

Всем привет, у меня есть input в котором нужно выбрать файл. При нажатии на кнопку выбрать файл перекидывает на другую страницу и открывается диалог. После выбора файла мы остаёмся на той же странице. Как запретить перенаправление на другую страницу?

Код:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display:none;" onclick="open(this)"/>
<p onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">Open</p>
<script>
function open(input) {
        let file;
        file = null;
        file = input.files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file)
        let result = reader.result;
        reader.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = result;
        };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` - это нативная функция (`window.open`). Просто переименуйте функцию